# How can I forward a public path to another Catalyst controller?

Tags: perl, catalyst

Let say the public URL /faq is linked to the private path /faq/index in my Catalyst application:

```
package MyApp::Controller:FAQ;
sub index :Path {
[....]
```

How can I do a forward to /faq from another controller, that is how can I know that the action for the URL /faq is /faq/index ? Something like:

```
$c->forward(c->dispatcher->get_action_by_path( "/faq" )); # does not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer for the Catalyst mailing list:

```
my $path = "/" . join '/', @{$c->req->args};

$c->request->path($path);
$c->dispatcher->prepare_action($c);

$c->detach($c->action, $c->req->args);
```